# How to set zoom level to each markers in google map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

If i have 4 markers,
marker 1 should be only visible at zoom level 1-3,
marker 2 should be only visible at zoom level 4-7,
marker 3 should be only visible at zoom level 8-11,
marker 4 should be only visible at zoom level 12-15.

Comment: `map.getZoom()`

Comment: this method will only tell me at which zoom level map is at.how do i give the zoom level to marker